# Is there any way to simply store a string or other variable permanently without the use of a DB in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server

Is there any way to store a variable in nodeJS kind of like localStorage but for the server?
For example store a JSON object as a string for a small amount of data?

Comment: How "permanent" do you mean?  Would a session var work?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter a variable that would remain and that would be callable  over several days. A session var would not be applicable because it could only be used while the session remained open.

Comment: You could use Redis to store data in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally. Check out the [file system module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) that comes with Node. You can then just write to a file and then read it/change it/etc.

```
let myData = {
    something: 42,
    else: "a string!"
}

fs.writeFile('db.txt', JSON.stringify(myData), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The data has been saved!');
});
```

You could also consider something like [redis](https://redis.io/) which is technically an in-memory database but is very straight forward to use. You should leverage a client like [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) to easily store and retrieve data.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take a look and see if this works!